# HDMI wount stay off

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, hdmi

After updating my computer to 19.10 Kubuntu sound is unusable. 
It switches it to monitors the soundcard and sets it to default. nothing seems to work.
Before the update setting it off worked.

**Swiched off**

[image: Swiched off]

**It switches HDMI on**

[image: It switches HDMI on]

**And sets it default**

[image: And sets it default]

Comment: Actually I think its a bug. But I fixed it with that. And I did not find that answer by myself. and I tried to uncomment other modules before. Now it switches on by itself bot it's not default anymore. ty I can't upvote yet.

Comment: I upvoted your question to bring you one step closer to upvoting powers.